# Redis memory optimization

Tags: python, optimization, redis

I am trying to encode some data ( a very big string actually ) in a very memory efficient way on the Redis side. According to the Redis docs, it is claimed that "use hashes when possible", and it declares two configuration parameters:

- The "hash-max-zipmap-entries", which if I understood well it denotes how many keys at most every hash key must have ( am I right?).
- The "hash-max-zipmap-value", which denotes the maximum length for the value. Does it refer to the field or to the value, actually? And the length is in bytes, characters, or what?

My thought is to split the string ( which somehow has fixed length) in such quantities that will play well with the above parameters, and store them as values. The fields should be just sequence numbers, to ensure a consistent decoding..

**EDIT**: I have benchmarked extensively and it seems that encoding the string in a hash yields a ~50% better memory consumption.

Here is my benchmarking script:

```
import redis, random, sys

def new_db():
    db = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6666, db=0)
    db.flushall()
    return db

def db_info(db):
    return " used memory %s " % db.info()["used_memory_human"]

def random_string(_len):
    letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890"
    return "".join([letters[random.randint(0,len(letters)-1)] for i in range(_len) ]) 

def chunk(astr, size):
    while len(astr) > size:
        yield astr[:size]
        astr = astr[size:]
    if len(astr):  
        yield astr 

def encode_as_dict(astr, size): 
    dod={}
    cnt = 0
    for i in chunk(astr,size):
        dod[cnt] = i
        cnt+=1
    return dod


db=new_db()
r = random_string(1000000)
print "size of string in bytes ", sys.getsizeof(r)
print "default Redis memory consumption", db_info(db)
dict_chunk = 10000

print "*"*100
print "BENCHMARKING \n"

db=new_db()
db.set("akey", r)
print "as string " , db_info(db)
print "*"*100

db=new_db()
db.hmset("akey", encode_as_dict(r,dict_chunk))
print "as dict and stored at value" , db_info(db)
print "*"*100
```

and the results on my machine (32bit Redis instance):

```
size of string in bytes  1000024
default Redis memory consumption  used memory 534.52K 
******************************************************************************************
BENCHMARKING 

as string   used memory 2.98M 
******************************************************************************************
as dict and stored at value  used memory 1.49M
```

I am asking if there is a more efficient way to store the string as a hash, by playing with the parameters I mentioned. So firstly, I must be aware of what they mean.. Then I'll benchmark again and see if there is more gain..

**EDIT2:** Am I an idiot? The benchmarking is correct, but it's confirmed for one big string. If I repeat for many big strings, storing them as big strings is the definite winner.. I think that the reason why I got those results for one string lies in the Redis internals..

Comment: If you're talking about a cryptographic hash, it's impossible to decode them, as an infinite number of different strings map to any given hash.

Comment: Cryptographic hash? I am only trying to store a big string efficiently in a Redis hash, by splitting it at Ai chunks, where len(Ai) < "hash-max-zipmap-value". Then I can restore it using the chunk_sequence_number, which is the field that holds every Ai.

Comment: I don't know anything about Redis, but "hash" and "decode" often mean someone doesn't understand about how hash functions work. I don't know whether or not it applies to this situation.

Comment: Ok then :), a Redis hash is a data structure identified by a key, and has fields and values. The hashing is done internally in Redis, to hold those fields and values.. With them I can decode back my string..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, the most efficient way to store a large string is as a large string - anything else adds overhead. The optimizations you mention are for dealing with lots of short strings, where empty space between the strings can become an issue.

Performance on storing a large string may not be as good as for small strings due to the need to find more contiguous blocks to store it, but that is unlikely to actually affect anything.

Answer (score 4):

I've tried reading the Redis docs about the settings you mention, and it isn't easy.  But it doesn't sound to me like your plan is a good idea.  The hashing they describe is designed to save memory for small values.  The values are still stored completely in memory.  It sounds to me like they are reducing the overhead when they appear many times, for example, when a string is added to many sets.  Your string doesn't meet these criteria.  I strongly doubt you will save memory using your scheme.

You can of course benchmark it to see.

Answer (score 2):

Try to look at [Redis Memory Usage](http://nosql.mypopescu.com/post/1010844204/redis-memory-usage) article where you can find a good comparison of various data types and their memory consumption.

Answer (score 0):

When you storing data in a hash you will just skip ~100 bytes per value overhead!

So when your string length is comparable, 100-200 bytes for instance, than you may see 30-50% memory savings, for integers it's a 10 times less memory though!

Here is couple of links:

[About 100 bytes overhead](https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools/wiki/Redis-Memory-Optimization#avoid-small-strings)

[Different memory optimization comparision gist](https://gist.github.com/alekseyl/07be456e52c2a47ceb8e4d11156ea674)